# Java JFrame and Graphics

Tags: jframe, java, graphics

У меня такой вопрос, выдает ошибку при выполнении о переполнении стека: 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.jazzteam.Shapes.fillRect(Shapes.java:8)
        at org.jazzteam.Shapes.fillRect(Shapes.java:8)
        at org.jazzteam.Shapes.fillRect(Shapes.java:8)

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, пытался искать по гуглу, ничего толкового не нашел, с английским очень плохо, никогда не изучал =/.

Код программы:

```
package org.jazzteam;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameField {

    public static void gamefield() {
        Shapes shapes = new Shapes();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GameField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        shapes.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gamefield();
    }
}

Код класса Shapes: 
package org.jazzteam;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Shapes {
 public void fillRect(int x, int y, int height, int width) {
  fillRect(x, y, height, width);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то типа этого

```
 import java.awt.Graphics;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class MainClass extends JPanel {

      int s1 = 0;
          int s2 = 0;
      int s3 = 0;
          int s4 = 0;

      public void setParams(s1, s2, s3, s4) {
      this.s1 = s1;
          this.s2 = s2;
      this.s3 = s3;
          this.s4 = s4;
      }
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(s1, s2, s3, s4);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    MainClass painter = new MainClass();
    painter.setParams(20, 20, 20, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(painter);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Это понятно, но как мне сделать так, чтобы  g.fillRect(0,0,200,200); в этом объекте координаты менять при вызове этой функции, а не в самом коде этой функции?

Comment: Хотя все, я понял что в функции я сделал, что вызываю её саму себя с её параметрами, а ничего не рисую и она в это время бесконечно сама себя вызывает и происходит переполнение.

Comment: поправил ответ

Comment: угу, я уже понял свою ошибку, спасибо за разъяснение в комментариях к первому ответу.

Answer (score 1):

У вас рекурсивный вызов функции 'fillRect'.

Comment: public void fillRect(int x, int y, int height, int width) {
      fillRect(x, y, height, width);
     }


гениально =)

Comment: Что не так?))

Comment: Вы не видите рекурсию или не знаете что это такое?

Comment: На сколько я понял, что просто оно бесконечно начинает выполнять эту функцию и поэтому стек переполняет =/ . Пойду гуглить что такое рекурсия :)

Comment: именно! и мне не понятно что вы пытаетесь этой функцией сделать.

Comment: Я хочу чтобы из класса SHapes, функция рисовала объект  на фрейм в классе GameField, но чтобы я могу указывать параметры фигуры в самом глассе геймфилд при вызове функции.

Comment: ваша функция может быть и такой, только в ее теле вам нужно вызывать fillRect у соответствующего объекта

Comment: да, неправильно, ты же дал ей только имя, а внутри ее вызываешь ее же... она пустая.. тебе надо создать холст для рисования и на нем рисовать фигуры...